# Ruby & Rails 4 - sqlite3 save DOB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sqlite

I'm using the Ruby Gem "Simple Forms" to register a user. I'm using the Ruby Gem "Devise" for the users. 
The input on my simple form is:

```
<%= f.input :dob, label: "Date of Birth", as: :date, start_year: Time.now.year - 13, end_year: Time.now.year - 90, order: [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

I used the line below for the db migrate:

```
rails g migration add_dob_to_user dob:text
```

I saved it as a text data type because I read online that there is no date data-type in sqlite3, but I could be wrong.

When I try and save the info I get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"9MpP91lDCMe/FT+SXrSJfpywYNgeqp7KU/TfalPkdJs=",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"guppy",
 "dob(3i)"=>"19",
 "dob(2i)"=>"12",
 "dob(1i)"=>"2001",
 "email"=>"branw@gmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I was wondering how to successfully save the birthday (dob) to a user when they register without giving me the error:

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [19, 12, 2001] to dob (wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1))]
```

Thanks a ton <3

Comment: I changed the datatype to :date and it worked... So i guess date is a thing in sqlite3... ffs

Comment: I think it is that Rails expects the screwy multipart format to go into a date, it probably doesn't know how to mash it into a string. BTW, SQLite stores times and dates as ISO8601 formatted strings because it has no native date or time types.